# Django - Aggregate equal values of fields in model

Tags: python, django, aggregation

I have activity logs for user activities, basically structured like this:

```
class ActivityLog(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    object_raw = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I want to aggregate all the entries where object_raw matches, i.e. so if a user searched for 'foo' on 4 different occasions, I get back one entry for 'foo', with count=4. I'm having trouble doing this right now. I know how to do it in sql, but don't understand that django syntax. I've been reading through the docs but I still don't get it. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get one object with `'foo'` and how many objects have `object_raw='foo'` you can do:

```
activity_logs = ActivityLog.objects.filter(object_raw='foo')
if activity_logs.exists():
    activity_logs.first()  # get one object
    activity_logs.count()  # get number of objects
```

If you just want how many objects have `object_raw='foo'`, you can use [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) with [aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions):

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Sum
Client.objects.aggregate(
    num_object_raw=Sum(
        Case(
            When(object_raw='foo', then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)
```